# Shikandini married uncle's daughter?

Tags: mahabharata, shikhandi

Mahabharata, in this translation, says Hiranyavarman gave his daughter to Drupada's son Shikandini (Drupada said she is his son when she was a girl). Hiranyavarman was about to attack Drupada and all the sorted when Shikandini temporarily became male.
During these passage, Drupada keeps addressing Hiranyavarman as "my brother". More [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05195.htm).

> The reply to these words of **my brother** that thou hast said unto me, O Brahmana, will be carried to that monarch by my envoy!

And,

> Hearing that testimony, the ruler of the Dasarnakas was filled with great joy, and wending then **unto his brother** Drupada, passed a few days with him in joy.

In the previous sections also there are referenced as brothers.

Question is, of they (three two kings) were brothers, Hiranyavarman's daughter and Drupada's son (daughter) will be brother and sisters. So, marriage was between brother-sister here?

Comment: As per text looks like marriage indeed happened between "paternal cousins", which might have been a violation of scriptural injunctions at that time. But, again, exceptions and accommodations have always been a part of Hinduism even mytho-theologically and Philosophically, ex:- Draupadi, Prachetãs, etc. So this too MIGHT have been another exception perhaps.